# Pass all template types to operator without specifying all types

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, operators, overloading

Is it possible to pass all template types to a operator? The `__Depth` objects assignment operators have all been overloaded and I'm tring to overload the color channel operators without having to write every single color depth and channel combinations.

```
struct Depth8
    {
        unsigned char Depth;

        void operator =(const Depth16& _Depth)
        {
            Depth = 255 * _Depth.Depth / 65535;
        }
    };
    struct Depth16
    {
        unsigned short Depth;

        void operator =(const Depth8& _Depth)
        {
            Depth = 65535 * _Depth.Depth / 255;
        }
    };


template<class __Depth>struct ColorRGB
    {
        __Depth R;
        __Depth G;
        __Depth B;

        void    operator =(ColorBGR& _Color) // << Want to do this instead of..
        {
            R = _Color.R;
            G = _Color.G;
            B = _Color.B;
        }

void    operator =(ColorBGR<__Depth>& _Color) // << this..
            {
                R = _Color.R;
                G = _Color.G;
                B = _Color.B;
            }

void    operator =(ColorBGR<Depth16>& _Color) // << or this..
            {
                R = _Color.R;
                G = _Color.G;
                B = _Color.B;
            }
    };
        };
```

Comment: You can use compiler-generated copy constructor / assignment.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but those identifiers are [best avoided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations). Also, I don't quite follow what it is you are asking. Would you clarify a bit? You can refer to the [ask] section of the [help] for tips on improving your question.

Comment: Im trying to overload the assignment operator without specifying the template __Depth, all __Depth are a depth object eg 8bit, 16bit and all there operators have been overloaded.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have updated, does that shed some new light?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what this post is about. After fixing your broken code sample, it works *exactly* like you want. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b5e49b3043b2488

Comment: @StoryTeller To  do this. ColorRGB<Depth8> = ColorBGR<Depth16>. Obviously can overload it but with all combinations it would take alot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template for member to avoid repetition:

```
template<class Depth>
struct ColorRGB
{
    Depth R;
    Depth G;
    Depth B;

    ColorRGB(const Depth& r, const Depth& b, const Depth& g) : R(r), G(g), B(b) {}

    // Allow conversion between different depths.
    template <class Depth2>
    ColorRGB(const ColorRGB<Depth2>& rhs) :
        R(rhs.R),
        G(rhs.G),
        B(rhs.B)
    {
    }


    template <class Depth2>
    ColorRGB& operator =(const ColorRGB<Depth2>& rhs)
    {
        R = rhs.R;
        G = rhs.G;
        B = rhs.B;
        return *this;
    }



    ColorRGB(const ColorRGB& rhs) = default;
    ColorRGB& operator =(const ColorRGB& rhs) = default;
};
```

The template version doesn't handle copy constructor, but fortunately, default one is OK.